# Proxy server prevents to access the node server of the blockchain for the Marbles

Tags: blockchain

I can not proceed with the Marbles. Just received the message below.  I think our company's proxy server is preventing.  Will you tell me any URLs relating to the server?

"Waiting on the node server to open up so we can talk to the blockchain. This app is likely still starting up. Check the server logs if this message does not go away in 1 minute. "

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that the Blockchain service on Bluemix is being used, so suggestions are made based on this assumption.

The message could be displayed when the chaincode for the demonstration has not completed deployment. Chaincode can take a couple of minutes to deploy. Although the message mentions waiting one minute, it would be good to wait around five minutes after the chaincode deployment was started to determine if the message changes.

If there is an underlying problem with the chaincode deployment, a different message should eventually be displayed. If the content of the message never changes, then the chaincode and validating peer logs should be reviewed.

To check if the chaincode deployed and review chaincode logs:

1. Select the **Dashboard** choice from the menu (horizontal bars) on the top left of the Bluemix interface.
2. Under **All Services**, click on the name of the Blockchain network that has been created.
3. Press the **Launch** button in order to work with this Blockchain network.
4. On the **Network** tab, scroll to the bottom to see the chaincode list.
5. If a chaincode has been deployed, select the validating peer for which the chaincode logs should be reviewed and press the button to the right of the drop-down list in order to view the log.

To review validating peer logs:

1. Once the Blockchain network has been launched, navigate to the **Logs** tab.
2. Press the **Logs** button next to each validating peer to review the logs.

Concerning the possibility of a proxy blocking access, you can make sure that the REST port is accessible.  Obtain a validating peer address from the **Network** tab of the dashboard and then append /chain (such as https://blockchain-network-ID-vp0.us.blockchain.ibm.com:port/chain).  This should return the chain height and hash.  If not, then it is likely that a port is being blocked.